# Modulus Hosting options

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, modulus.io

Can someone just confirm that Modulus is a web host exclusively for NodeJs and cannot support something like a WordPress blog installation? I ask for a friend I'm helping out whose engineer built a platform on using nodejs and mongo hosted on Modulus. She wants to add a Wordpess blog (with my help) because her engineer doesn't have time to do integrate a native one.

I believe I know the answer. No, Modulus is just for Node. So alternatively I told her she'll have to create a sub domain with her modulus account. Host her blog on her  hostgator account and redirect the hostgator URL to the sub domain created on Modulus.

Added 10/7/14 ---

I would like to point a site hosted at hostgatorsitename.com/blog to blog.modulusitename.co so that it seems like the blog is hosted on blog.modulusitename.co. For example, if there is a blog title "My Blog Title", the url would read blog.modulusitename.co/my-blog-title.

Is there anyway to do this? If so, how specifically can I go about it? If not, is it because the WordPress installation has to actually exist on blog.modulusitename.co and cannot be hosted elsewhere if we need the url to read this way?

Thanks in advance for all assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, you've got it right. Modulus is only for node hosting.  You're solution will work.  Host the blog on any other platform and create a subdomain to point to it.